# My computer is still showing remnants of the old Apple ID

Tags: imac, apple-id

I used to have an Apple ID that I shared with my family, but it was becoming more and more obvious that I would end up needing my own. So I got myself an Apple ID, got family sharing set up, and switched everything out on my iPad. When I got to my computer, things got more complex. First, I logged out of iCloud and logged into my Apple ID instead. Then, I switched iMessage, FaceTime, Game Center, and a few other things. The problem is, my computer is still showing remnants of the old Apple ID. Is there a way to completely switch Apple IDs with one login on an iMac? Or do I just have to switch everything as I go along?

(Edit:) It would be too inconvenient to create a new user account because I have a lot of settings to applications adjusted and my computer too rigged up.

Comment: Not directly the solution you are looking for, but is it feasible for you to create a new user account and move your data and system customizations  to that account? While, many would say this should be the last approach, it will give you a neat and clean setup configured completely with your new Apple ID.

Comment: @NimeshNeema I have to say I like the set up I have now. Also, moving internet applications over would be hard because I would have to re-download them and configure my settings again from scratch.

Comment: You won't need to re-download the installed apps from the Internet. All apps installed in `/Applications` directory will be automatically available in the new user account.

Comment: @NimeshNeema but not with my configured settings

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @NimeshNeema That would be hard because I have added a bunch of add ons and configured a lot of settings.

Comment: If you can edit the question with specifics on `my computer is still showing remnants of the old Apple ID.`, maybe we can workout a solution which doesn't require creating a new user account.

Comment: I mean  can you expand this statement and add further details in the question? : `The problem is, my computer is still showing remnants of the old Apple ID. `. That will help in getting relevant answers.

Comment: What apps show the old apple I'd ?

Comment: @Mark For one, iTunes. I have no idea how to switch iTunes to my Apple ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple does have several places for id - I have for historic reasons 2 different ids and so note some of the differences.

There are actually separate places that have logins.

1. iCloud/Mail login
2. iTunes login for music/vides etc
3. iPad/iPhone app store
4. MacOS store
5. Apple developer (I have several different ids here)

I have one id for 1 and another for the rest and others for 5. But I think the Mac Appstore could be set as a different id.

2 and 3 might  be the same (although that could be historic as iOS apps were updated via iTunes)

This does mean that you will need to change id separately for 1,2,4 and 5 (I think 2 and 3 are covered by one change)